# Exporting a map with changing number of elements to CSV

Tags: c++, visual-c++, csv, dictionary

I need to export data from 3 maps to preferably a single CSV and would like to be able to do so without simply making a column for every possible key (there may be up to 65024 of them).

The output would be a CSV containing the value at each of the keys at each timestep (may be several hundred thousand).

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can we get some more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the granularity by categorizing your keys into groups and store them with one timestep per row.  Then you can plot one datapoint per line.

Let me know if you need clarification, i'd need some more info.